# Is there a Ruby function to perform an XOR operation on two sets of strings?

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

I have two Arrays of strings, and I would like to find the set of strings not in the intersection of both. The equivalent of SETXOR in MATLAB is what I want:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setxor.html

I'm using the term set interchangeably with Array.

Of course, I could have just as easily written my own in the time taken to form this question, but I thought I should ask.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
array1 + array2 - (array1 & array2)
```

It was shorter, than to write a question...

By the way, Ruby has a class [Set](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Set.html), so better not to use this word as a synonym to an Array.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, as Nakilon says, Set.

```
require 'set'
s = Set.new('a'..'f')
a = ['f','d','e','e','h','i'] #or any enum
p s ^ a  #=> #<Set: {"h", "i", "a", "b", "c"}>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of having Set as a data structure? Thank you for your solution.

Comment: A set is a collection of values, without duplicates. It features fast insertion, deletion and membership testing. At least the last one is useful for your question.

Comment: Set is an under appreciated class, for reasons @steenslag gives. Sadly ^ does not seem to be aliased ('exclusive_or' would be ideal) unlike the other Set operators

Comment: You can also use `.to_set` to convert most enumerables: `( array1.to_set ^ array2 ).to_a` (converting the second array to a set isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can always just do

```
(array0 - array1) + (array1 - array0)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [2, 5, 8]
(a - b) + (b - a)
  # => [1, 3, 4, 8]
```